# insert into table where column increments by 1 when compared with other rows of the same data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I will essentially have a table with data like

```
id, parent_id, child number
1, 5, 1
2, 5, 2
3, 5, 3
4, 5, 4
5, 6, 1
6, 6, 2
```

What I need is an SQL Query that would be able to add a row representing a new Child of parent id 5, so would be told something along the lines of

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`parent_id`)
VALUES ('5')
SET `child_number` = 1 + MAX(`child_number`) WHERE `parent_id` = '5'
```

But i doubt that that sql would work.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Could you be a little clearer, inserting a row with a parent id of 5 seems pretty simple doesn't it?

Comment: The 2 answers provided pretty much hit the nail on the head by the looks of things

Comment: What are you planning on doing with this information?  Is this something that would be better derived?  What happens if a row is deleted - do you need to update all "greater" `child number`s?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse The new child number always wants to be a number 1 greater than the greatest existing child number for that parent id, but it doesnt matter if any of the lesser ones get deleted, deleting or updating any row in the table should require no interaction with any other row as long as they stay unique.

Comment: If you allow gaps, then why does each `parent_id` need its own sequence?  What are you using this information for?  Why couldn't you just use the `id` column, and declare that there were lots of "pre-deleted" rows?

Comment: its basically tables within a table - for each of my parent objects, i need list of children of undetermined size, so parent 1 needs a table with the id of its children, so this is being expressed by all rows in the table with parent_id = 1 , so for parent 1's data you just treat it as a table only including data where parent_id = 1 and the IDENTITY is the child id. There may be a better way, but this seems to work in my head.

Comment: Yeah on further thought, i have ditched this technique, it would have worked, made sort of sense, but was overcomplicating things all in all. Part of the process i guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an insert query like this:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (PARENT_ID, CHILD_NUMBER)
VALUES
('5', (SELECT MAX(CHILD_NUMBER)+1 FROM TABLE WHERE PARENT_ID= '5') );
```

Comment: Thank you, looks good. I feel i should have been able to figure it out but my brain wasn't operating.

Comment: @Merry - Note that this **must** serialize inserts to this table, or you could end up with duplicate values.  If you have a unique key that includes the column, you wouldn't get duplicate values, but it _would_ require that you attempt the insert again.  This solution will at minimum lock all records with the given `PARENT_ID` for the duration of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `table` SET 
    `parent_id` = '5',
    `child_number` = (SELECT MAX(`child_number`) FROM `table` WHERE `parent_id` = '5') + 1
```

Comment: @Merry - Note that this **must** serialize inserts to this table, or you could end up with duplicate values.  If you have a unique key that includes the column, you wouldn't get duplicate values, but it _would_ require that you attempt the insert again.  This solution will at minimum lock all records with the given `PARENT_ID` for the duration of the transaction.